# Struggling with installing Audacious, which requires pkg-config

Tags: unix, cygwin

Title should be self-explanatory. I thought the pkg_config installation didn't give me errors at all, so I assumed it installed fine, but I got this error when installing Audacious.

How do I deal with path to make sure that pkg_config is set up correctly?

```
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.
```

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -c pkg-config` ?

Comment: `Cygwin Package Information Package              Version        Status`

Comment: This means you have NOT installed the `pkg-config` package. Re-run cygwin setup and install it  https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: I swear I DID install pkg-config in the package list in the installation process... I'm also doing it in a new computer and therefore reinstalling a lot of things - and this is what I've got when trying to install Audacious..:
```Package 'glib-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GLIB_CFLAGS
and GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.```

Comment: Output of cygcheck -c pkg-config: ```Package              Version        Status
pkg-config           1.6.3-1        OK
``` Hm, looks like I correctly installed it this time